# How do I change the Android Manifest to skip login screen and launch the Application instead

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest

The developers doesn't support application anymore, so login options unavailable.  I would like to skip login screen and launch the Application instead. Can I change the Android Manifest in order to do that?
Could anyone help?

The app isn`t available at Google Store anymore, but can be found here: https://www.apk4fun.com/apk/239138/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.searchlike" platformBuildVersionCode="26" platformBuildVersionName="8.0.0">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE"/>
<permission android:name="com.searchlike.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.searchlike.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_READ"/>
<uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_WRITE"/>
<meta-data android:name="android.support.VERSION" android:value="25.3.1"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.searchlike.MainApplication" android:resizeableActivity="false" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_live_opyq0ew8g6mMmHYn4ipBeamdutiwNotx"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/icon_notification"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/theme_blue"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fb_app_id"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:theme="@style/com_facebook_activity_theme"/>
    <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.searchlike.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.searchlike.fcmopen"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:host="open" android:scheme="searchlike"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="searchlike.app.link" android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:host="searchlike-alternate.app.link" android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:host="searchlike.test-app.link" android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:host="searchlike-alternate.test-app.link" android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:host="m.lzr.ai" android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="be5f8dca0dd9bc907c780c5063740e13dafb4a5b"/>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService"/>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener"/>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.kochava.base.ReferralReceiver"/>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.androidbroadcastreceiverforreferrer.ReferrerBroadcastReceiver"/>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.searchlike.ReferrerForwarder">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:authorities="com.searchlike.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="com.imagepicker.FileProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity"/>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
    </service>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"/>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"/>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="com.searchlike"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity"/>
    <provider android:authorities="com.searchlike.crashlyticsinitprovider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" android:name="com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider"/>
    <provider android:authorities="com.searchlike.firebaseinitprovider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity"/>
    <provider android:authorities="com.searchlike.MarketingInitProvider" android:exported="false" android:name="com.facebook.marketing.internal.MarketingInitProvider"/>
    <provider android:authorities="com.searchlike.FacebookInitProvider" android:exported="false" android:name="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider"/>
    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.facebook.CurrentAccessTokenExpirationBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ACTION_CURRENT_ACCESS_TOKEN_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: The news aggregation is most likely done by their server. If you do not log in, their server will not return any data, even if you are able to start the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that most of your activities are Google/Facebook/Twitter SDKs

So the only activity left is `com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity`

Your manifest should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.searchlike" platformBuildVersionCode="26" platformBuildVersionName="8.0.0">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />
  <permission android:name="com.searchlike.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.searchlike.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_READ" />
  <uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_WRITE" />
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.VERSION" android:value="25.3.1" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.searchlike.MainApplication" android:resizeableActivity="false" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_live_opyq0ew8g6mMmHYn4ipBeamdutiwNotx" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/icon_notification" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/theme_blue" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fb_app_id" />
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:theme="@style/com_facebook_activity_theme" />
    <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="be5f8dca0dd9bc907c780c5063740e13dafb4a5b" />
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" />
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.kochava.base.ReferralReceiver" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.androidbroadcastreceiverforreferrer.ReferrerBroadcastReceiver" />
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.searchlike.ReferrerForwarder">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:authorities="com.searchlike.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="com.imagepicker.FileProvider">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService">
      <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService">
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
    </service>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService" />
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.searchlike" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService">
      <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.searchlike.crashlyticsinitprovider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" android:name="com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.searchlike.firebaseinitprovider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.searchlike.MarketingInitProvider" android:exported="false" android:name="com.facebook.marketing.internal.MarketingInitProvider" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.searchlike.FacebookInitProvider" android:exported="false" android:name="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider" />
    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.facebook.CurrentAccessTokenExpirationBroadcastReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ACTION_CURRENT_ACCESS_TOKEN_CHANGED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put below snippet of code in `manifest` file only inside the `activity` tag of that specific `activity` which you want to launch first when app starts.

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

For Example: You want to launch `com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity` activity first when app starts then your `manifest` file for this `activity` will look alike:

```
<activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```